# How to add "Continue Shopping" button next to "View Cart" button in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[image]

I am working on WooCommerce site, for some reason I want to display "Continue Shopping" button and "View Cart" button together after adding product to the cart. I found the file wc-cart-function.php that says Output success message to show message but I couldn't return view cart and continue shopping's $message variable with single return `$message`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way.

```
function filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) { 

    $return_to = apply_filters( 
        'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 
        wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) 
    );

    $continue   = sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', 
        esc_url( $return_to ), 
        esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ) 
    );

    $message .= $continue;
    return $message; 
}; 

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
```

For more details take a look at "wc_add_to_cart_message_html" hook.

Comment: This works fine.  The 'Continue Shopping'  button returns to the current Product page.  How/where can it be changed to return to the 'Shop' page?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change `wc-cart-functions.php` file and want to return continue shopping button with the View Cart button just write the code in else part of
`if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) )` condition
in `wc-cart-functions.php` file given below.

```
$message   .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
```