# "Continue Shopping" button next to "View Cart" button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

An original question was 'solved' here:
[How to add "Continue Shopping" button next to "View Cart" button in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041009/how-to-add-continue-shopping-button-next-to-view-cart-button-in-woocommerce)
With the following code:

```
function filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) { 

    $return_to = apply_filters( 
        'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 
        wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) 
    );

    $continue   = sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', 
        esc_url( $return_to ), 
        esc_html__( 'Continue','woocommerce' ) 
    );

    $message .= $continue;
    return $message; 
}; 

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
```

But it produces the following html:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
    <a href="https://.../cart/" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">View cart</a>
     &ldquo;Front Suspension Bump Stop Spacer&rdquo; has been added to your cart.
    <a href="https://.../product/.../" class="button wc-forward">Continue Shopping</a>  
</div>
```

i.e.

- A view Cart button.
- A Product has been added text message
- A Continue Shopping button.

Is it possible/easy to change the sequence, so that:

- the Product has been added ..message
- is followed by the two buttons.

This will make the css much easy to align the two buttons better on both wide and narrow screens?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to have first the text followed by the 2 buttons:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products, $show_qty ) { 
    $titles     = array();
    $count      = 0;
    $product_id = null;

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        /* translators: %s: product name */
        $titles[] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_qty_html', ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ), $product_id ) . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes', sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) ), $product_id );
        $count   += $qty;
    }
    $titles = array_filter( $titles );
    
    /* translators: %s: product name */
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
    $message    = esc_html( $added_text );
    $btn_class  = wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '';
    $return_to  = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    $message   .= sprintf( ' <a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_attr( $wp_button_class ), esc_html__( 'Continue', 'woocommerce' ) );
    return $message . sprintf( ' <a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward%s">%s</a>', esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ), esc_attr( $wp_button_class ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

You will get the following HTML structure:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert"> 
    “Front Suspension Bump Stop Spacer” has been added to your cart. 
    <a href="https://xxxxxx/product/xxxxxx/" class="button wc-forward">Continue</a>
    <a href="https://xxxxxx/cart/" class="button wc-forward">View cart</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks the two buttons 'VIEW CART' and 'CONTINUE' display fine, and I've even understood :) some of the code and been able to wrap them in an inline div.  But the 'CONTINUE' button link returns to the product page - although, we want, it to return to the SHOP page.     An earlier line includes "wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) )"  but doesn't seem to get used?